# Apache RewriteRule error adding Locales to new URL

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, configuration, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am in the process of redirecting a URL and I wanted to use the 'RewriteRule' directive when in the process of doing so.

I currently have a rule as follows:

```
 RewriteRule ^/application/web/reservation/index.jsp https://application.domain.com/application2/web/reservation/audioForm.zul [R,L]
```

However I also want this to work if a locale is added to the end of the first URL.  It could be various different locales (never static), so I want the RewriteRule to take whatever comes after '.jsp' in the first URL and place it after '.zul' in the second.

For example something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/application/web/reservation/index.jsp(*)$ https://application.domain.com/application2/web/reservation/audioForm.zul$1 [R,L]
```

I believe I have the syntax wrong for the replacement portion:

```
(*)$ and $1 respectively
```

Just so you can see what the link looks like with the locale, I have placed an example below:

```
https://application.domain.com/application/web/reservation/index.jsp?locale=de-DE
```

I would want to place '?locale=de-DE' after .zul in the second URL.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Actually your own answer is not correct.

**To match a specific** (specific word is important here) **query string**, such as the example you mention "?locale=de-DE'" you would **need a RewriteCond** doing it.

But in this specific case, since the target url is not specifying a query string, default behaviour from mod_rewrite is to append the original query string (whatever it was) to it unless you specify the QSD flag (query string discard).

So, briefly:

```
RewriteRule ^/application/web/reservation/index.jsp https://application.domain.com/application2/web/reservation/audioForm.zul [R,L]
```

or even:

```
RewriteRule ^/application/web/reservation/index.jsp$ https://application.domain.com/application2/web/reservation/audioForm.zul [R,L]
```

would match a request for:
"/application/web/reservation/index.jsp?whatever" 
and would append whatever query string to the target you specified:
"https://application.domain.com/application2/web/reservation/audioForm.zul" because it does not specify a query string.

Comment: Thank you!  The above way I did it seemed to work for me, but it does not seem to be the correct way to accomplish what I am looking to do based on your explanation.  Let me test your method and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out after a couple hours of playing around and researching the mod_rewrite API.

[Apache Module mod_rewrite - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Instead of:

```
^/application/web/reservation/index.jsp(*)$
```

I used:

```
^/application/web/reservation/index.jsp(.*)
```

Comment: Yes, because mod_rewrite uses regular expressions and not globs.